# JavaScript how to reverse this animation, after click another link

Tags: javascript, css

```
    $('#home').click(doWork);

function doWork() {
        var index = 0;
        var boxes = $('.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6');

        function start() {
            boxes.eq(index).addClass('animated');
            ++index;
            setTimeout(start, 80);
        };
        start();
    }
```

when i click a link, this animation start . And after end the animation, i need to reverse this animation, after click another link.

Comment: Your question is not too clear. Please post the related html markup to better replicate this issue.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `setTimeout(start)` **in** `start()`. You'll have an exponential pile of `start()`s.

Comment: @trojansdestroy That's called recursion. The `setTimeout` delays each call. What's wrong with that? I mean, there's a few things I would change about this, but the main point is fine

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want, but http://jsfiddle.net/WPjvF/

Comment: @Ian My mistake. I read it as `setInterval`.

Comment: @trojansdestroy Ahh I see. Haha yeah, that would've been bad...

Comment: ian your answer is what i exactly want. thanks so much.

Comment: @ian in your http://jsfiddle.net/WPjvF/ , when i click start button 1st time its work corecctly, but after clicking reverse button, then i click again  start button "ahh6" 6 is appering first. how to correct it.

Comment: What stops the recursive calls to start?  At some point the index will exceed the array size, is that causing an exception or ?? that prevents the next call to `setTimeout`?

Comment: @user2607456 Sorry about that. After you said it was what you were looking for, I went to make an answer and found that problem as well as others, so I started editing my code. I just posted an answer with updated code and the demo, so hopefully that works for you and is better

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that allows you to start the process, as well as interrupt it to do the reverse:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var doWork,
        index,
        boxes,
        numBoxes,
        workerTO;

    index = 0;
    boxes = $(".box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6");
    numBoxes = boxes.length;
    doWork = function (changer, reverse) {
        var direction, worker;

        clearTimeout(workerTO);

        direction = reverse ? -1 : 1;
        worker = function () {
            if (reverse) {
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = 0;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (index >= numBoxes) {
                    index = numBoxes - 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            console.log(index);
            changer(boxes.eq(index));
            index += direction;
            workerTO = setTimeout(worker, 80);
        };
        worker();
    };

    $("#home").click(function () {
        doWork(function (el) {
            el.addClass("animated");
        });
    });

    $("#home2").click(function () {
        doWork(function (el) {
            el.removeClass("animated");
        }, true);
    });
}());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NcdZT/1/

I'm sure some things could be condensed and made more efficient (like the `if` statements), but this seems readable and achieves what you want.

Keeping track of the `setTimeout` allows the process to be interrupted. If you increased the timeout from 80 to something more noticeable (or if you click fast enough), you would see that the "animation" can be reversed midway through.